# Slow bash script for getting audio/video duration

Tags: performance, bash

I have created a bash script to generate a HTML file, which will have the duration of the audio/video files in the current folder. The script uses `ffprobe` to fetch the duration in the quiet mode and `file` to get the mime-type. Although, the script works as intended, **it feels a bit slow. I was wondering if it is possible to speed it up**. 
However, I don't have any experience in scripting and don't know about any time profiling tools. I did come across a stackoverflow answer on that topic, but time profiling can't suggest new libs or methods.

I did come across a suggestion on the SO from the python world using opencv and the benchmarks looked promising, but I am wary of installing such a huge library, and its big or small dependencies, just for this.

```
#!/bin/bash

today=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")
file=$(printf "duration-${today}.html")
tot_dur=0
echo "<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #f5f5f5;}
</style>
</head>
<body>" >> "${file}"
echo "<table>" >> "${file}"
echo "<tr>
        <th>File</th>
        <th>Duration</th>
      </tr>" >> "${file}"
while read filename
do
    mime=$(file -b --mime-type "${filename}")
    IFS='/' read -r -a mime <<< "$mime"
    if [[ $mime == "video" || $mime == "audio" ]]; then
        duration=$(ffprobe -v quiet -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 -show_entries format=duration "${filename}")
        tot_dur=$(echo $tot_dur + $duration | bc -l)
        duration=$(printf '%02d:%02d:%02f\n' $(echo -e "$duration/3600\n$duration%3600/60\n$duration%60"| bc | xargs echo))
        echo "<tr><td>"${filename}"</td><td>"${duration}"</td></tr>" >> "${file}"
    fi
done < <(ls)
# (find . -type f)
tot_dur=$(printf '%02d:%02d:%02f\n' $(echo -e "$tot_dur/3600\n$tot_dur%3600/60\n$tot_dur%60"| bc | xargs echo))
echo "<tr>
        <td><b>Total</td>
        <td><b>${tot_dur}</td>
      </tr>" >> "${file}"
echo "</table>" >> "${file}"
echo "</body> </html>" >> "${file}"
```